System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'lesi.Collections
The error is System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
'lesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet 1' from assembly
'lesi.Collections, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral
I have checked all the versions and lower it to 3.1.0 but it's also not working. It's asking for 4.1.0.0 version.the version I have installed for Iesi.Collection is 4.1.1 and NHibernate is 3.1.0 . I don't know how to solve this problem.
I'm expecting to run the code without this exception.This exception is giving me HTTP error 403.3.
Exactly I don't know what it is
